# Is it possible to use PHP with the HTML "Value" attribute

Tags: php, html, button, paypal

Im working on a checkout page and ive used a text document and some PHP to be able to change the price at one place (the textdocument) and it will change over the whole website on its own. but i got a problem where i need to insert the price into a HTML Value attribute but i cant get it to work with the PHP script. im mainly going to use it for a normal paypal button.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?$file = ("textfile.txt");
    $read = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = fread($read, filesize($file));
    echo $data;
    fclose($read);?>">
```

Here is the code ive tried but it doesnt work and i just get an error when clicking the button: "The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount."

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: This `value="<?$file = ("textfile.txt");` is an issue. Don't bunch up `<?$file` like that, including `($read);?>` - Plus, make sure short open tags are on. You'd most likely want to do `<? $file` or `<?php $file` - However, doing it this way seems almost wrong.

Comment: You should inspect your HTML source and see what PHP returns in the value attribute, to possibly see what you could do to fix it. Usage of the PHP shorthand opening tag `<?` is discouraged. But if you do use it make sure to have a space between the question mark and anything else that comes after.

Comment: Using `<form><input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php $file = ("textfile.txt");
    $read = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = fread($read, filesize($file));
    echo $data;
    fclose($read); ?>"></form>` worked perfectly well. **HTML source:** `<form>

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="Hello world">

</form>`

Comment: Yet `<form><input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?$file = ("textfile.txt");
    $read = fopen($file, "r");
    $data = fread($read, filesize($file));
    echo $data;
    fclose($read);?>"></form>` worked also (having tags bunched up as you have it now), so make sure that short open tags are ON. If not, changed `<?` to `<?php` - Make sure you have `<form></form>` tags. If that doesn't work, then you'll need to come up with another method.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your code a lot simpler by just using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo file_get_contents('textfile.txt'); ?>">
```

Note that the PHP tags are also changed.  [Short tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) might be disabled so you shouldn't rely on them.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the contents of your textfile.txt, I can't be sure, but make sure it does not contain anything to designate the currency type ($, USD, etc). It should only contain a float value like 5.02